# Is there a way to retrieve the Number of the contact that successes JB Acitivity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, ssjs, sql

I'm trying to retrieve the Number of the contact that successes JB Acitivity via SSJS or SOQL whatever. please check the highlighted part of the image I attached.That's the thing I'm trying to retrieve. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an API you can use to retrieve summary on journey builder activities:

```
Host: {{your_rest_base_uri}}
POST  /interaction/v1/interactions/{{journey_definition_id}}/activities/{{activity_id}}/summary
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
Body: Nil
```

The response includes "**successCount**" which is what you're looking for.
You can find the journey definition ID using the following [endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getInteractionCollection.html?q=%24name):

```
Host: {{your_rest_base_uri}}
GET   /interaction/v1/interactions?nameOrDescription={{name_of_journey}}
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
```

Comment: You'll also need the permission "journeys_read" under your scope.

Comment: really appreciate your help. you are my life saver :))))))

Comment: @SujinHwang No worries. Please accept my it as the correct answer if you find it helpful :) Thanks.